# Jquery UI droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is Jquery UI droppable able to interact with files inside computer? Lets say I have an image file on my pc not inside the *webpage* where I try to drop on it and trigger a simple alert to notify. Is that possible with just Jquery UI ?

Comment: Eric, the jQuery droppable event handling you are talking about are all for objects inside of a webpage. Drag and Dropping files themselves (from the host computer) have to be done using 2 HTML5 APIs: File API and DND Api. The tutorial that Shaz linked is the right way to get started with those APIs (it is why I wrote it -- I started looking at jQuery/plugins and hit a brick wall so I kept researching until I figured out how to do it). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what you described, use [HTML 5 Drag & Drop](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) instead. To answer your question, I don't believe JQuery UI allows you to do this.

Comment: the URL you gave has been taken over by scammers. Could you update the link? Thanks,